# Вызов конструктора базового класса только из конструктора производного

Tags: c#

Есть базовый класс и производный от него, можно ли и как сделать чтоб конструктор базового класса вызывался только через base в конструкторе производного, и нельзя было создать только базовый экземпляр без производного? тоесть чтобы обязательно был производный...

Comment: просто сделать базовый класс `abstract`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- abstract base class
- protected base class constructor